# Nesting Do Loop and Try Catch

Tags: java

I'm creating a menu where the user should input "1", "2" or "3" depending on which options he wants, but if he types something wrong, let's say "4", he'll get an error message and will be brought to the menu again. Should I nest Do Loop inside Try Catch, or the opposite? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `switch-case` instead!

Comment: Don't use try/catch for normal program flow. Use it only for exceptional situations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `try-catch` in the loop. You can use simple `switch-case` instead.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(in.hasNext()) {
        switch(in.nextInt()) {
            case 1: System.out.println("1 Entered..."); break;
            case 2: System.out.println("2 Entered..."); break;
            case 3: System.out.println("3 Entered..."); break;
            default: System.out.println("Invalid!");
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
1
2
5
```

Output:

```
1 Entered...
2 Entered...
Invalid!
```

Comment: You might want to include breaking out of the loop if a valid choice is made.

Comment: @Tiz Yes, he can put a `break` and get out of the loop any time he wants.

Answer (score 1):

```
int g =0;
while(true) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
        g = input.nextInt();
        if(g<0){
         break;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Not a valid input. Error :");
        //continue;
    }
}
```

if you are using a `try catch block` inside your `while loop` be careful the `exception will be thrown` bt the `loop` will continue since the condition at while loop is true so you need to `break` the `while` loop and you can continue the loop if you use `continue;` inside the catch block which i have commented in  my code

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use loops here.

You can use `if else if` or just use a `switch` cases.

```
switch (input) {
  case 1:  
     // menu 1;
     break;
  case 2:
     // menu 2;
     break;
   case 3:
     // menu 3;
     break;
   default:
     // error
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to use object-orientation for such things, most notably the command pattern in combination with a factory.

```
public interface Command {
    String name();
    void execute();        
}

public class OptionOne implements Command {
    public String name() {
        return "1";
    }
    public void execute() {
         System.out.println("Executing option 1");
    }
}

// command classes OptionTwo and OptionThree omitted

public class CommandFactory {

    private static final Command[] commands = {
        new OptionOne(), 
        new OptionTwo(),
        new OptioneThree()
    };

    public static Command getInstance(String input) {                        
        for (Command command : commands) {
            if (command.name().equals(input)) {
                return command
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no command known for input: " + input);
    }
}

public class Application { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = args[0].trim();
        try {
            CommandFactory.getInstance(input).execute();
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // logged message
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            // message for the user
            System.out.println("Could not handle input");
        }                       
    }
}
```

This is just to show the idea. The code is untested.

In general, when you find yourself creating a condition or switch which will need a new segment for every use case you add in the future, it is generally better to use a pattern such as this one to encapsulate the logic in separate classes.